# Calculating the probability of finishing service first

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I have a job where the service time follows an exponential distribution with mean $1/\mu$. At the same time, there are new customers coming in with Poisson rate $\lambda$. As soon as they arrive, they start a job whose service time follows an exponential distribution with mean $1/\mu$. I would like to know the probability that I finish the job first (i.e., there are no incoming customers, if any, finishes their job before me).

Things I tried:

(1) Conditional on my own service time, then integrate over my service time. This looks very complicated.

(2) Assume $x_k$ is the probability that when $k$ people (other than me) are currently doing their job and I am still the first to finish. The original question asks for $x_0$.

I can write the system of equations according to the exponential race:

$$
x_n=\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda+n\mu}+\frac{n\mu}{\mu+\lambda+n\mu}x_{n-1}+\frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda+n\mu}x_{n+1}
$$
where the first term stands for the case where I finish the first, the second term stands for the probability that a customer other than me finishes the first, and the third term stands for a new arrival happens first. Then I am not sure how to solve this.

Any hints will be extremely helpful. Thank you!

Edit:
$$
x_n=\frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda+n\mu}+\frac{\lambda}{\mu+\lambda+n\mu}x_{n+1}
$$

Comment: I think you should delete the middle term, since if one of those other $n$ people win, we are done. So you can write $x_n$ in terms of $x_{n+1}$ only.   You also know $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n=0$.

Comment: @Michael That's right! Thanks!

Comment: The sequence $x_n$ is interesting but looks hard to solve.  Another (direct) way to solve is to do the first:   If $X$ is your own service time and $N$ is the random number of arrivals during your service, condition on $X=t$ and $N=n$, then use the fact that, given $N=n$ and $X=t$, the $n$ arrival times are independently and uniformly distributed over the interval $[0,t]$.